# TypeError: Data location must be “memory” for parameter in function, but none was given

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, truffle-migration, truffle-contract

Contract fail to  compile in IDE Remix.due to the following error:

> TypeError: Data location must be "storage" or "memory"  for parameter
>   in function, but none was given.

```
version:0.5.6+commit.b259423e
```

I have no idea why this happened and i have not found any sufficient information on how i can fix it and was hoping you can help me. Thank you in Advance.

The error points to this function:

```
function bytesToAddress(bytes bys) pure private returns(address addr) {
        assembly {
            addr := mload(add(bys, 20))
        }
```

Comment: Change `bytes bys` to `bytes memory bys`.

Comment: Thanks..that fix it but now points to the following: TypeError: "send" and "transfers" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address"  The error poins to this line:    msg.sender.transfer(amount);
            contractfunds.transfer(msg.value.mul(DEVWORK).div(1));

Comment: Thanks..that fix it but now points to the following: TypeError: "send" and "transfers" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address"  The error poins to this line:    msg.sender.transfer(amount);
            contractfunds.transfer(msg.value.mul(DEVWORK).div(1));

Comment: There are no `send` or `transfer` or `msg.sender.transfer(amount); contractfunds.transfer(msg.value.mul(DEVWORK).div(1))` in your question!!!

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be

```
function bytesToAddress(bytes memory bys) ...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify them as addresses.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/65609/52189

I had a piece of code that had to change from :

```
user_address.transfer(this.balance);
```

to in `0.5.0` solidity:

```
address(uint160(user_address)).transfer(address(this).balance);
```